# ModSecurity : PCRE limit settings do not have any effects

Tags: php-fpm, apache2, mod-security

I'm facing `Rule execution error - PCRE limits exceeded (-8): (null).` errors when I ask ModSecurity to analyse body data (using the `SecRequestBodyAccess On` directive).

I've read about the problem, and I tried to increase the limit, both on Apache2 and php-fpm :

**/etc/apache2/apache2.conf**

```
SecPcreMatchLimit 5000000
SecPcreMatchLimitRecursion 5000000
```

**/etc/php/8.0/fpm/php.ini**

```
[Pcre]
pcre.backtrack_limit = 1000000000
pcre.recursion_limit = 1000000000
```

I restarted both Apache2 and PHP-FPM services using systemctl, and I still hit the `PCRE limits exceeded`. The two configurations seems to not be loaded.

How can I make sure the configuration is loaded ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, the configuration was written in the **/etc/apache2/apache2.conf** instead of **/etc/modsecurity.conf**